# CodeIgniter 2.1 and SimpleTest - Conducting a simple test

Tags: php, codeigniter-2, simpletest

I am currently using CI 2.1 and Netbeans 7.0 as my inveiglement IDE.  I would like to create some simple unit testing using SimpleTest.  In particular the methodology used by Eric Barnes and his code found at Git Hub CodeIgniter-SimpleTest. (https://github.com/ericbarnes/codeigniter-simpletest)

I have created a new CI application using Netbeans 7.0 and connected to my database (which contains 1 table called **schools** with the typical schema schoolid, schoolname, schooladdress etc.).  I have created a controller (simpleapp), which loads a model called **schools_model**.  The schools_model gets all the schools using a method called **getAll()**.  Another method called **getSchoolName(id**), accepts a school ID and returns the school name.

The controller then loads a view called **schools_view** to display all the schools.  Pretty simple stuff…....... and it works flawlessly, displaying all the schools when I point my browser to

http://localhost/SimpleTest/simpleapp/getAllSchools

(I am also using a .htaccess file, hence no index.php)

My question is this….......

How do I get SimpleTest to work using the Git hub code supplied by Eric?

I have followed Eric’s set-up advise, but don’t know what URL to point to to create the screen dumps he provides.  I have maintained the directory structure Eric suggests but haven’t had any success.  Eric suggest to point the browser to **yoursite.com/unit_test.php**, but I get a
404 page not found error for localhost/SimpleTest/unit_test.php

I assume the above error is due to the fact, like most CI applications, we need to use a controller first.

I would appreciate any direction in this area.

---

I have done exactly what you suggested.  I have placed the unit_test.php file in the root directory and set up the test directory structure as suggested.  However, when I point to **localhost/SimpleTest/unit_test.php** I get the 404 error.

My directory structure looks like

Source Files

```
-application (folder)
-system(folder)
-tests(folder from git hub with model/test_schools_model.php)
-.htaccess
-index.php
-licence.txt
-unit_test.php
```

Is it a .htaccess issue the reason I cannot view localhost/SimpleTest/unit_test.php?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct you need to go to yoursite.com/unit_test.php or in your case localhost/SimpleTest/unit_test.php

You need to copy the unit_test.php file from github into the sites root directory and place the tests directory there too. You then put your tests in the appropriate folder under tests/